# Ruby ternary operator

Tags: ruby, jruby, ternary-operator

Why aren't these two statements equivalent?

1. `defined? foo ? foo << "bar" : foo = ["bar"]`
2. `if (defined? foo) then foo << "bar" else foo = ["bar"] end`

First statement:

```
irb(main):001:0> defined? foo ? foo << "bar" : foo = ["bar"]
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> foo
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> defined? foo ? foo << "bar" : foo = ["bar"]
=> "expression"
irb(main):004:0> foo
=> ["bar"]
```

Second statement:

```
irb(main):001:0> if (defined? foo) then foo << "bar" else foo = ["bar"] end
=> ["bar"]
irb(main):002:0> foo
=> ["bar"]
irb(main):003:0> if (defined? foo) then foo << "bar" else foo = ["bar"] end
=> ["bar", "bar"]
irb(main):004:0> foo
=> ["bar", "bar"]
```

These sessions are with JRuby 1.5.0 (should be equivalent to native Ruby 1.8.7).  I see slightly different behavior with native ruby 1.9.1: statement #1 never defines `foo` even when running it twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the first evaluates to:

```
defined?(foo ? foo << "bar" : foo = ["bar"])
```

Why that returns nil, I have no clue...

The fix is simply to do:

```
(defined? foo) ? foo << "bar" : foo = ["bar"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of that!

Comment: "Why that returns nil, I have no clue..": When I enter that very first line of the question "defined? foo ? foo << "bar" : foo = ["bar"]" in an irb console I get "expression" and not "nil". I think there was a mistake by the questioner.

Comment: @Mörre It depends on what version of ruby you are using.  You are probably using ruby 1.9.

Comment: Indeed I do. I could not imagine someone would still voluntarily use 1.8, it's soooo "yesterday" :)

Comment: @Mörre: Of course I did fiddle in IRB to have my answer correct ;-P And I'm getting `nil` as well, having Ruby 1.8.7 which is what comes with Mac OS X Snow Leopard...

Comment: The comment was for completeness' sake - I had already given you a +1 vote too.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. defined? foo ? foo << "bar" : foo = ["bar"]
> 2. if (defined? foo) then foo << "bar" else foo = ["bar"] end

In either case, your code could probably be simplified. Based on the two samples above it looks like there'd be an enclosing loop of some sort. Rather than try to create `foo` inside it and initialize to the first `['bar']`, I'd do something like:

```
foo = []
... start some loop ...
  foo << bar
... end some loop ...
```

Or, if you don't like breaking up the initializer from where you append to the array:

```
(foo ||= []) << "bar"
```

This second way is a bit "Perlish", but it's not so far gone from the Ruby-way to be undecipherable.